# Blazor Table Input Being Replicated in the Following Cell

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table, blazor, user-input, blazor-server-side

I've been trying to get help on this for weeks and have just been instructed by the GitHub AspNetCore/Blazor team that I need guidance from someone in this forum before they can look at it.

This issue is that data input into a Blazor generated table that contains input statements with either value or placeholder data doesn't behave as expected, and in fact behaves differently depending on how the Blazor component markup is coded.

In particular, I have a component that contains an html table with embedded input elements in each td cell, some showing previous user-entered data (via a value attribute) and the others showing default values (via a placeholder attribute).  There's a reason I am doing it this way. When I enter data in a default (placeholder) cell that’s followed by 2 more default cells *in the same row*, the entered value ends up formatted in the 1st cell (as expected) and appears unformatted in the 2nd cell (unexpected). Also, if I enter the data using the tab key, the cursor ends up in the 3rd cell (unexpected), even though the onfocus events indicate the 2nd cell has focus.  On top of that, while analyzing this, I discovered that if I generate what should be the same table with different markup, the data input behavior is different.

I've created a GitHub [demo](https://github.com/CincySteve/BlazorTableInputDemo) that's as tight as I can make it. It includes 2 comments in the markup, which is in the MainLayout component, showing how to change the markup and the behavior.  To reproduce the problem, do the following after starting the app:

- Enter 99 in the default cell that's showing $51 (1st cell) and hit tab.
- Notice that "$99" appears in the 1st cell (expected) and "99" (without the $) appears in the next/2nd cell (unexpected), which had shown $52 as a default placeholder. Also notice that the cursor ends up in the 3rd ($53) cell.
- Change the if statements in the markup that are pointed out as changing the behavior.  Repeat the first two steps.
- Notice in the VS Output Window what things look like when onchange, onfocusin, onfocusout and afterrenderasync fire.

This looks to me like a framework issue.  But perhaps there's something wrong in what I am trying to do.  If it is the framework, I need someone in this forum to say that in order to get the GitHub team to take a look.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why is our data table being rendered in MainLayout? That is not the right place for content to be rendered. Anyway, that is not the problem - 99.9% sure your problem is that you haven't learned to use the `@key` directive in your loops. [Read about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't heard of @key.  In my app, cell Values can be changed, but the set of cells is fixed. I added @key="cell" to each input and found the unexpected value in the 2nd cell no longer showed (great!).   But the cursor disappeared after data entry (tab or enter).  And if I hit tab twice, the cursor reappears in the 4th (last) cell in the row, indicating it was in the 3rd cell.  Is there a way to have the cursor appear after data input and not have it end up in the 3rd cell when tab is used?  I used MainLayout to make the demo as small as possible as requested by the GitHub team.

Comment: I would use `@key` on the `td` not the input - it is just as unique but higher up the tree. This could account for the lost cursor as well - if the input(s) are being dropped and re-created.

Comment: That fixes the problem.  Thanks.  The keep-it-simple in me still thinks the code without "@key" should work and that having to use @key, which doesn't tie to an equivalent standard html attribute, is not desirable.  Anyway, I can move on using your idea.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can't really keep it simple when you are conditionally rendering - the code that handles changes in the render tree cannot see your code, all it has to go in is "I have a TD - does it match with a TD in this position before?" Which is prone to disaster when you have logic that renders different things in the TD

Comment: So, adding a `@key` is just saying "hey this thing here is important - don't swap it out even if it moves position"

Comment: Helpful perspective.  Thanks again.